# Firefox ALT+S keystroke to enter address bar

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Moin,

as my company recently updated FF from german to proper english, I miss the ALT+S keystroke to enter the address bar.

Is it possible to set it with about:config?

Christian

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `ALT+D` or `Ctrl/Cmd+L` (from [this site](http://lifehacker.com/139495/hack-attack-mouse+less-firefox))

Comment: This is pretty what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark: It does indeed work in IE, however, annoyingly it pops up a dialog to take your input instead of just focusing in the URL bar.

Comment: @Bryan, just to clarify: Ctrl+D works as expected/advertised. Ctrl+L opens the Open Location dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

there is <kbd>F6</kbd> ... if you want

Answer (score 1):

you can try the keyconfig addon. it is not in mozilla addon, but it helped me a lot.
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994

Comment: it actually lets you change the ctrl+l shortcut to alt+s or whatever you'd like.

Comment: i'll have to try that out when i get some spare time. if it let's me assign a keyboard shortcut to show and hide the Navigation and Bookmark toolbars I'll be a happy kid

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifWinActive, Mozilla Firefox
!s::!d
#IfWinActive
```

in the AutoHotKey scripting language would remap that for you :)
Not sure if there's a native solution, unfortunately!